# Windows.Phone.Media.Capture.PhotoCaptureDevice is obsolete ...?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm working on a camera app and I need to use advanced settings like exposure, ISO and so on.

According to [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj206940(v=vs.105).aspx) ( August 19, 2014 ) or [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj662940(v=vs.105).aspx), I have to use the "PhotoCaptureDevice" class instead of the "Camera" class.

The problem is when I'm using it on Visual Studio Premium 2013 update 3 with a windows phone 8.1 project, I got the following warming:

> 'Windows.Phone.Media.Capture.PhotoCaptureDevice' is obsolete: 'Windows.Phone.Media.Capture may not be available in future versions of Windows Phone. Starting with Windows Phone Blue, use Windows.Media.Capture instead'

Who am I suppose to listen to, Visual Studio or msdn manual?

Comment: It sounds like there were three classes, two of which are now obsolete. Camera became Phone.Media.PhotoCaptureDevice which became Media.Capture; Visual Studio is showing the latest information.

Comment: Why the microsoft manual didn't mentioned it ?

Comment: Because Microsoft doesn't go back and update every MSDN article with every update to their software. You will still find many articles on MSDN that suppose IE5 is the latest version of that product.

Comment: ah ok ! Do you have any example of how to use "Capture" please ?

Comment: Is it Windows.Media.Capture or Windows.Media.CaptureDevice ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is pretty simple to use.

The complete example application is available here:

[MediaCapture class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.media.capture.mediacapture.aspx) scroll to the bottom.

---

As for your **advanced settings** assuming your `MediaCapture` is named `mc` then it's all in
the

```C#
mc.VideoDeviceController structure
```

[VideoDeviceController MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.media.devices.videodevicecontroller.aspx)

---

And you can set these settings by doing something like this:

```C#
// set the brightness (0 representing blanking and 10000 representing pure white)
mc.VideoDeviceController.Brightness.TrySetValue(5000);
```

Comment: Thank you for this information, but I was wondering : The example use a CaptureElement in XAML which is working in Windows Runtime project, I'm working on a Windows 8.1 Silverlight. I tried to use videoBrush.setSource(mediaCapture) but it doesn't work, what should I use ?